# Attaching camera preview to multiple container (e.g picturebox)

Tags: c#, camera

im using avicap32 api to stream camera  preview to picturebox and successful. My problem is, how to copy those live preview in other form/picturebox or it is possible to attach single camera to multiple container/picturebox at the same time. Currently  my technique is to  have a main form (provider) that attach to camera and use a timer to periodically capture the content of the picturebox and put the image to static image variable. On the other form (subscriber) i also use timer to periodically get the value of the static image variable and load to the picturebox of that form. It seems successful (tried 2 to 3 instance of subscriber forms) but when i use an mdi form (tried 2 instance) as as subscriber, its just get single image and stop displaying image. when i tried closing the 1 mdi subscriber. the remaining mdi form resume displaying image. what seems to be problem.. tnx

```
//attachment 

public bool Attach(System.Windows.Forms.Control control)
        {
            bool ret = false;

            deviceHandle = Avicap32.capCreateCaptureWindow("", _WM_Constants.WS_VISIBLE | _WM_Constants.WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 320, 240, control.Handle, 1);

            if (User32.SendMessage(deviceHandle, _WM_Constants.WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, (IntPtr)deviceNumber, (IntPtr)0).ToInt32() > 0)
            {
                User32.SendMessage(deviceHandle, _WM_Constants.WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, (IntPtr)(-1), (IntPtr)0);
                User32.SendMessage(deviceHandle, _WM_Constants.WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, (IntPtr)0x42, (IntPtr)0);
                User32.SendMessage(deviceHandle, _WM_Constants.WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, (IntPtr)(-1), (IntPtr)0);
                User32.SetWindowPos(deviceHandle, new IntPtr(0), 0, 0, control.Width, control.Height, 6);
                ret = true;
            }
            return ret;
        }

//capture
public Image Capture()
    {
        if (deviceHandle.ToInt32() != 0)
        {
            User32.SendMessage(deviceHandle, _WM_Constants.WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
            IDataObject ido = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            if (ido.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                return ((Bitmap)ido.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

// image holder
public static class app_config
{
       public static Image camerashot;
}

//image capturing from provider form

private void tmrCamera_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            app_config.camerashot =((CaptureDevice)cboDevices.SelectedItem).Capture();
} 

//image retrieval from subscriber form


private void tmrCamera_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            picCamera.BackgroundImage = app_config.camerashot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem found. Main form or picturebox with attached camera should be on top window. i always lunch mdi form (subscriber) in maximized window state covering main form (provider)